# Select 'some' random points from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two related numpy arrays, `X` and `y`. I need to select `n` random rows from `X` and store this in an array, the corresponding `y` value and the appends to it the index of the points randomly selected.

I have another array `index` which stores a list of index which I dont want to sample.

How can I do this?

Sample data:

```
index = [2,3]
X = np.array([[0.3,0.7],[0.5,0.5] ,[0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.9]])
y = np.array([[0], [1], [0], [1]])
```

If these `X`'s were randomly selected (where `n=2`):

```
randomylSelected = np.array([[0.3,0.7],[0.5,0.5]])
```

the desired output would be:

```
index = [0,1,2,3]
randomlySelectedY = [0,1]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd manage an array of boolean values that I continually use to slice an index array and randomly choose from the result.

```
n = X.shape[0]
sampled = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool)
sampled.fill(False)
rng = np.arange(n)

k = 2

while not sampled.all():
    sample = np.random.choice(rng[~sampled], size=k, replace=False)
    print(X[sample])
    print()
    print(y[sample])
    print()
    sampled[sample] = True

[[ 0.2  0.8]
 [ 0.5  0.5]]

[[0]
 [1]]

[[ 0.3  0.7]
 [ 0.1  0.9]]

[[0]
 [1]]
```

Comment: @scutnex depends on what you mean by record.  I am updating the `sampled` array with `True` values... that is recording it.  This is an algorithm for doing it.  There are many things that could be tweaked according to taste.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select `n` rows at random, with an equal probability of choosing any row:

```
n = 2 #for sake of argument
randomlySelectedY = np.argsort(np.random.random(4))[:n] #generate a 1x4 array of random, uniformly distributed numbers and then select the indices of the lowest n numbers

randomylSelected = X[randomlySelectedY]
index = np.linspace(1,np.size(X[:,1]),np.size(X[:,1]))
```